# Get value from an ajax modal onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax, modal-dialog

I m trying to get the value of a row id inside a modal called with Ajax.

I would like to get the row id (data-id) from the modal.

the JavaScript function "onRowClick" is working for the table in the main page but not for the one in the modal.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ehkd8L22KZb0xxCnubUb?p=preview

```
<DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/modalit@0.1.6/dist/MODALit.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/modalit@0.1.6/dist/MODALit.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="table1">
    <tr data-id="1"><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="2"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr data-id="3"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
</table>
<hr />
<div style="color:green" id="row-value">-</div>
<hr />
<!-- Sets modal target -->
<button type="button" id="button" data-src="modal.html">Modal Open</button>
<script>
    var modal = new MODALit({
        el: '#button',
    });

    window.onload = onRowClick("table1", function (row) {
        var rowid = row.getAttribute("data-id")
        //alert(rowid);
        document.getElementById("row-value").innerHTML = rowid;
    })

    function onRowClick(tableId, callback) {
        var table = document.getElementById("table1"),
            rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            table.rows[i].onclick = function (row) {
                return function () {
                    callback(row);
                };
            }(table.rows[i]);
        }
    };

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Ajax content (modal.html):

```
<table id="table2">
 <tr data-id="1"><td>Row 1</td></tr>
 <tr data-id="2"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
 <tr data-id="3"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
     window.onload = onRowClick("table2", function (row) {
        var rowid = row.getAttribute("data-id")
        //alert(rowid);
        document.getElementById("row-value").innerHTML = rowid;
    })

    function onRowClick(tableId, callback) {
        var table = document.getElementById("table2"),
            rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            table.rows[i].onclick = function (row) {
                return function () {
                    callback(row);
                };
            }(table.rows[i]);
        }
    };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ehkd8L22KZb0xxCnubUb?p=preview

How can i get the data-id of the row inside the modal ?

Comment: where is ur ajax i cant see wt ur tried tell me this as same nothing is changed

Comment: The ajax is the file (modal.html) , is it call whn you click on "Modal Open" button -> http://plnkr.co/edit/ehkd8L22KZb0xxCnubUb?p=preview

Comment: s dude  on click modal called not ajax call

Comment: It's an ajax call from the Modal plugin: https://knot-design.jp/MODALit/